# Bulk Deletion of Rally Test Cases using Java

Tags: java, rally

I need to delete several test cases i have in rally. Rally website says that the only way around this problem is to communication with Rally API and write a small bulk deletion script.

E.g. i need to delete from TC100 - TC150.

Anyone can help me with this? I am using java.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per [Rally Rest toolkit for Java](https://github.com/RallyTools/RallyRestToolkitForJava/wiki/User-Guide) documentation there is a [Delete](https://github.com/RallyTools/RallyRestToolkitForJava/wiki/User-Guide#delete) method.

Here is a code example that queries test cases by a tag name and then bulk-deletes these test cases. Your query criteria will be different, but if you choose to identify test cases by tag, note that `Tags.Name contains "tag1"` returns test cases that may have more than one tag applied, and not only those that a single "tag1".

```
import com.google.gson.JsonArray;
import com.google.gson.JsonObject;
import com.rallydev.rest.RallyRestApi;
import com.rallydev.rest.request.QueryRequest;
import com.rallydev.rest.response.QueryResponse;
import com.rallydev.rest.request.DeleteRequest;
import com.rallydev.rest.response.DeleteResponse;
import com.rallydev.rest.util.Fetch;
import com.rallydev.rest.util.QueryFilter;
import java.net.URI;


public class GetTestCasesByTagAndBulkDelete {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        String host = "https://rally1.rallydev.com";
        String apiKey = "_abc123"; //use your api key
        String applicationName = "Find TestCases by Tag and bulk delete";
        String workspaceRef = "/workspace/12345";

        RallyRestApi restApi = null;
        try {
            restApi = new RallyRestApi(new URI(host),apiKey);
            restApi.setApplicationName(applicationName);

            QueryRequest request = new QueryRequest("TestCase");
            request.setWorkspace(workspaceRef);

            request.setFetch(new Fetch(new String[] {"Name", "FormattedID", "Tags"}));
            request.setLimit(1000);
            request.setScopedDown(false);
            request.setScopedUp(false);

            request.setQueryFilter(new QueryFilter("Tags.Name", "contains", "\"tag1\""));

            QueryResponse response = restApi.query(request);
            System.out.println("Successful: " + response.wasSuccessful());
            System.out.println("Results Size: " + response.getResults().size());

            for (int i=0; i<response.getResults().size();i++){
                JsonObject tcJsonObject = response.getResults().get(i).getAsJsonObject();
                System.out.println("Name: " + tcJsonObject.get("Name") + " FormattedID: " + tcJsonObject.get("FormattedID"));
                int numberOfTags = tcJsonObject.getAsJsonObject("Tags").get("Count").getAsInt();
                QueryRequest tagRequest = new QueryRequest(tcJsonObject.getAsJsonObject("Tags"));
                tagRequest.setFetch(new Fetch("Name","FormattedID"));
                //load the collection
                JsonArray tags = restApi.query(tagRequest).getResults();
                for (int j=0;j<numberOfTags;j++){
                    System.out.println("Tag Name: " + tags.get(j).getAsJsonObject().get("Name"));
                }
                System.out.println("deleting " + tcJsonObject.get("FormattedID")) ;
                DeleteRequest deleteRequest = new DeleteRequest(tcJsonObject.get("_ref").getAsString());
                DeleteResponse deleteResponse = restApi.delete(deleteRequest);
            }


        } finally {
            if (restApi != null) {
                restApi.close();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks nickm. Much help!